# Return identity of last inserted row from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-4.1

I am trying to return identity of last inserted row from a stored procedure.

A simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_name]
    @AuthorisationCode uniqueidentifier
AS
    INSERT INTO [tablename]
           ([AuthorisationCode]
           )
     VALUES
           (@AuthorisationCode
           )

 RETURN @@IDENTITY

GO
```

I am calling this stored procedure via Execute Scalar in Enterprise library 4.1.

It returns null. Anybody see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As an aside, it's best not to name procs with a sp_ prefix.  But maybe that's psuedocode anyway.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks good catch, but it is just psuedocode :)

Comment: **RETURNING** values is usually reserved for error handling (e.g. anything other than 0 means there was an error).

Comment: @brad it can mean anything, to be fair

Comment: @Mark, yes, it **CAN** mean anything you want; that's why I said it's "usually reserved".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say you should be using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as `@@identity` will return the identity of the last thing inserted (which may not be your stored procedure if multiple queries are running simultaneously).

You also need to SELECT it, not RETURN it.

`ExecuteScalar` will return the first column value from the first row of a result set.

So...

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

is probably more what you want.

Answer (score 7):

You should use select rather than return, but you should also use SCOPE_IDENTITY to prevent issues with the wrong identity being returned, @@IDENTITY is not limited to a specific scope.

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: +1 wish I could vote more than once; this is such an under-utilized keyword

Answer (score 0):

you should use `select @@identity`

Comment: I don't want to downvote you, but you should really use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead of `@@identity` (see MrEyes answer)

Comment: @@identity is probably fine in this case.  Understanding the difference between current identity, scope identity, and @@identity is important, but @@identity isn't always wrong.  What if there's a trigger which for some ungodly reason is changing the identity at insert time and you want to know the last identity inserted?  Then you'd need @@identity and scope_identity won't work.

Comment: yes Brad, that is true , using scope_identity is the better choice here. (well, not the better choice but, depends on your need i guess). Althouhg, at my answer, i was referring to the usage of "return". And downvoting is the right choice here, it is an important difference between the two.

Comment: @Patrick is right: `@@identity` is not always wrong. @futile, I don't think downvoting is the right choice when you clearly understood what would solved the OP's immediate problem: `SELECTING` the result when using `ExecuteScalar`