# New Row into SQL Server with Data Set [asp.net, c#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this code:

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 

cnn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Szkoda";
cmd.Connection = cnn;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Szkoda");

SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

DataRow drow = ds.Tables["Szkoda"].NewRow();

drow["Likwidator"] = tbLikwidator.Text;
drow["FirmaObslugujaca"] = DdFirma.Text;
drow["StanSzkody"] = DdStan.Text;
drow["CzyRegres"] = DdRegres.Text;
drow["KrajZdarzenia"] = DdKraj.Text;

ds.Tables["Szkoda"].Rows.Add(drow);

da.Update(ds, "Szkoda");
```

The question is how to get the inserted record ID? I read about scope but I don't know how I can use this in above code.

I want to get last ID to redirect to view form after save new record.
I'm looking for simplest solution:)

Comment: Welcome to SO. From the code you have posted I don't see anywhere any insert statement. You have built a sql command that selects all the records from the table called `Szkoda`. Where is the insert ? Thanks

Comment: i select all columns from "szkoda" and insert record by a datarow-NewRow(). on the left you have columns from db, on the right values from textboxes on form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that directly from the Update command of the DataAdapter. You need to prepare a custom insert command that contains two commands. The first insert your record, the second one returns the last inserted id from your connection

```
string insertText = @"INSERT INTO Szkoda (Likwidator,FirmaObslugujaca, 
                      StanSzkody, CzyRegres, KrajZdarzenia) 
                      values (@lik, @fir, @sta, @czy, @kra);
                      SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertText, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lik", tbLikwidator.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fir", DdFirma.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sta", DdStan.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cay", DdRegres.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kra", DdKraj.Text);
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
   int lastInsertedID = Convert.ToInt32(result);
   // now insert the row in your dataset table but instead of
   // da.Update(ds, "Szkoda"); call 
   ds.Tables["Szkoda"].AcceptChanges();
}
```

Of course this should go alongside with your existing code, but instead of calling Update just call AcceptChanges to your datatable to confirm the new record in your table

Comment: Ok, @Steve i will use your solution for a moment. but tell me, if two users in the same time insert record, this users would get id of records added by him??

Comment: Yes, [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920558/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-identity-identity-identity-and-ide) returns the ID generated in your connection and by your query. So if two users executes this code concurrently (more or less) each one receives the correct ID

Answer (score 0):

Aftre insert the record into table(using sql query, not stored procedure) from c# code, you can use Get Records function to Select last record id(not recommended, because in muliuser case, this will be wrong) using max() fucntion.

```
select * from Szkoda  where ID IN (select max(id) from Szkoda)
```

If you are using Stored Procedure to insert data, then Use `SCOPE_Identity()` in stored procedure, and use Output parameter to get value in c# code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testSP
  @Col1 VARCHAR(50),
  @Col2  VARCHAR(20),
  @new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT dbo.TestTable(Col1, Col2) SELECT @Col1, @Col2;
    SET @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

Refer this [Return identity of last inserted row from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315628/return-identity-of-last-inserted-row-from-stored-procedure)